# html placeholder attribute

Tags: html

i'm fairly new to html 5 and i am faced with a scenario where i want one input tag of type text to contain more than one field and corresponding placeholder(s) for it that disappear on entering those fields one by one. is it at all possible to do?

let me make it clear with an example-

```
<body>
name: <input type="text" placeholder="first name, second name">
</body>
```

now i want 'first name' to disappear when it is being filled while 'second name' still shows.
how can that be done? (if at all).
please help me out. 
thank you.

Comment: You need two text boxes for both names.

Comment: i figured that much...so it can't be done with one?

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be done in HTML, as the `placeholder` attribute is defined to work in a special way (when supported), and you cannot override that in HTML. You could simulate the desired behavior in JavaScript (not trivial), but then it would be safer to do it all in JavaScript and not with `placeholder` attribute at all.

If it is relevant that data is entered in specific format, like “first name, second name”, the only reasonably safe way is to give this information in static content before the field. (It’s only reasonably safe, since people may easily miss or misunderstand even explicit instructions.) Make sure that you indicate clearly whether the parts of the name are really to be separated by a comma, as your current formulation may suggest.

Then again, if a specific order is required, it is normally better to have separate fields.